# Why is it that array outputs have a () with a number next to it in VS code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio

Why is it that array outputs have a () with a number next to it in VS code?

Code:

```js
var Str = 'a string'

console.log(Str)

var Arr = [23, 'Charles']

Arr[0] = 20

console.log(Arr)

var Arr1 = ['Grace', 'Debbie', 'Debby']
Arr1[0] = 'Sophie'
console.log(Arr1)
```

Output:

```
a string
(2) [20, 'Charles']
(3) ['Sophie', 'Debbie', 'Debby']
```

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJmnK.png)

Comment: To show you how many elements it has?

Comment: Looks like the correct output on run. Did you expect different output on hash 0? You mention hash 0 on your assignment.

Comment: Plus OP runs console.log twice. After each definition.

Comment: What's hash 0??

Comment: @BenNye09 `hash 0` is a programming paradigm to place data in buckets on user defined names. Since `0` is explicit its on array bucket `0`. This hash easy way makes `Arr1["Ben"] = "Nye09"` possible.

Comment: But consider `["Ben2"]` or `["Ben3"]` declarations, that would require a sort algorithm to discover. So a "hash/bucket" algorithm is used for performance behind the scenes, in deference of available memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just the elements count. BTW, `console.log()` of any object (an array is also an object) is parsed in that way.

[image]